# Manually coloring dodged multiple bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to manually color dodged multiple bars in ggplot2. I am specifying the colors using **scale_fill_manual** but it is still using default colors as shown in the screenshot.

```
   library(ggplot2)
   library(dplyr)
   library(tidyr)

  # Some fake data

  by_state<- data.frame(
   state=c("Florida","New York","Nebraska","Nevada","Texas"),
   healthy=c(19,16,15,20,22),
   danger=c(2,4,6,2,1),
   warning=c(4,5,8,3,3),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
       )


   by_state%>%gather(Condition,value,-state)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=state,y=value,fill=Condition))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+ 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue", "orange"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `scale_fill_manual` to modify fills. Color only modifies color aesthetics, not fill aesthetics.

You can see this more clearly if you include both color and fill (increased size to highlight the color around the bars):

```
by_state%>%gather(Condition,value,-state)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=state,y=value,fill=Condition, color =Condition))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", size = 2)+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","blue", "orange"))
```

[image]